# HighChartsDate Picker With Series Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, datepicker

I'm attempting to use a jquery datepicker with a series chart from HighCharts. So far I've gotten the datepicker start and end date widgets working, however I'm having trouble with the actual implementation of the range selection.

http://jsfiddle.net/9dmftmom/

```
$( "#datepickerStart, #datepickerEnd" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    }  
});
```

I've created an onselect event to store the date for each object. However, I'm unsure how to get this to dynamically update in the y-axis settings for the high chart.

```
yAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
         min: [INSERT START DATE HERE],
         max: [INSERT END DATE HERE],
         title: {
             text: 'Timespan'
         },
         step: 1,
         plotLines: [{
            color: '#000000',
            width: 4,
            value: Date.UTC(2015, 09, 01, 18, 0, 0),
            zIndex: 5
        }]
     }
```

I've tried calling the dateObject itself like `datepickerStart.dateObject` however this doesn't seem to work. My lack of javascript knowledge is clearly showing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing with datepicker? are you sending start/end time to fetch data to fill the series? if not , simply use highstock, it has range selector built in

Comment: @nishithchaturvedi that's exactly what I'll be doing. I looked into using the range selector from highstock, but couldn't find a way to make it work with highcharts.

Comment: It won't work with highcharts but its advanced version highstock.js

Comment: You can implement kind of rangeselector, by calling setExtremes on axis. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hdt9yqff/2/

Comment: @SebastianBochan That worked beautifully, thank you sir. If you post a more in depth answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement kind of rangeselector, by calling setExtremes on axis.

```
$('input[name="crange"]').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
            xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
            extremes = xAxis.getExtremes(),
            index = parseFloat($(this).val()),
            range;

        switch (index) {
            case 0: //week
                range = 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //7 days 
                break;
            case 1:
                range = 31 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //31 days 
                break;
            case 2:
                 range = 3 * 31 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //quark days 
                break;
            case 3: //year
                 range = 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //1 year 
                break;
        }

        xAxis.setExtremes(extremes.max - range, extremes.max);
    });
```

Example: jsfiddle.net/hdt9yqff/2